# How to conditional format on a partial date match?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I have a set of data with various date columns using Excel 2010.  I want to highlight any cells matching:

```
01/01/*
```

That didn't work.

At the moment I am matching using separate rules in conditional formatting:

```
Cell Value - Equals to - 01/01/2015
Cell Value - Equals to - 01/01/2014
Cell Value - Equals to - 01/01/2013
...
```

and so on.

Is there a way to do it with one rule?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use one conditional formatting rule to do this. By defining the rule as a formula, you can use the following, where `A2` is the top-left cell in the range to which you are applying the rule:

```
=AND(MONTH(A2)=1,DAY(A2)=1)
```

Here's an example implementation. If you want to apply the rule to the data below, you would first select `A2:E34`.

[image]

Then click Conditional Formatting on the Home ribbon and select `New rule...`. Choose `Use a formula to determine which cells to format` and enter the formula I gave above (again, `A2` is the top-left cell in the range the rule is applied to). Set a format, click OK, and you're done.

[image]

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Instead of "cell value" select "**use a formula to determine which cell to format**", then for the formula enter:

`="01/01"=TEXT(<cell>,"dd/mm")`

Where `<cell>` is the address of the active cell of the selected range (e.g. A1)

### Update

For easier management of references:

- go to file - options - formula and check "R1C1 reference style"
- for cell reference just type `RC`:
  `="01/01"=TEXT(<cell>,"dd/mm")`
- you can change reference style back to the original

Comment: What if it's for the entire sheet, checking all columns and rows?

Comment: After doing the selection there'll be a cell slightly different highlighted then the others (typically in top left corner of the selection), that's the active one.

Comment: When using Conditional Formatting, understanding [relative, absolute, and mixed references](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Switch-between-relative-absolute-and-mixed-references-538396b3-990e-4b44-9d9c-28b4151d7d21) is important. You define the formula in one cell, but you control what it applies to in the previous window. For example, it's possible (with the right references) to create a conditional formula based on the contents of a single cell in a column that does something to an entire row.

Comment: I've used: 
="01/01"=TEXT($1:$1048576,"dd/mm")
If I select one cell, it works, but I need to apply this rule across whole sheet.

Comment: @user95437: please see updated answer

Comment: @user95437 You define the conditional formula based on a single cell (A1), not the whole range. The range the conditions apply to are defined in the Conditional Formatting Rules Manager. Behind the scenes, Excel handles extrapolating one from the other for each cell.